# Point from FeatureSet as Input to Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, point, buffer, features, python-script-tool

I'm looking to use a point on the map provided through a FeatureSet as an input to both a buffer and Select by Location. I have created the geoprocessing tool that works, but am having difficulty with getting this part to not provide errors.

```
inPts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.SetParameter(0, "sourcePt")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("sourcePt", "sourcePt_lyr")
```

"inPts" is my FeatureSet. Distance is the field is the distance value for my buffer. When I try and make the feature layer, it is telling me that "sourcePt" has no data source.

Is there a step that I'm missing like needing to define geometry?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like 'sourcePt' does have a source, you're making up that variable in the expression.

The SetParameter function operates as follows: SetParameter (index, value) - ([source](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameter.htm)), meaning that where you currently have 'sourcePt' should be an object.

Example:

```
inPts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.SetParameter(0, distance)
```

If 'sourcePt' does actually have a value associated with it (which from the code you've provided we cannot tell) then please include that as well.

Edit:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.env.workspace = "CURRENT"

csvFile = r"csv location"
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csvFile, "database file save location")

# Set the local variables
in_Table = r"database file save location"
x_coords = "x-coordinate header from csv"
y_coords = "y-cooydinates header from csv"
out_Layer = "layer name"
saved_Layer = r"lyr file location and name"
prjPath = "coordinate system location and name, if needed"
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management (in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer, prjPath)



# Add layer to mxd
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(out_Layer, saved_Layer)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"lyr file location and name")   #same as above
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")

# Buffer
```

see [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm)

Comment: should I be using inPts as my value? It is the first user parameter for my tool and is the FeatureSet from the point. Or am I doing too many steps and can just use inPts in my buffer?

Comment: What exactly is inPts, a shapefile, layer, etc.

Comment: It is a feature set. It is just an empty point that can be put anywhere on the map that I want to be able to be used as an input to both a buffer and later select by location.

Comment: In arcpy the buffer requires an in_feature, so as long as the feature set is physically saved on your mxd as a feature, you should be fine. As for the select by location you won't be using the feature set. Instead you'll likely use the out_feature_class from the buffer. I hope that helps.

Comment: how would I save the FeatureSet to the mxd? If this is supposed to be a one click tool. I know I can maybe create a scratch workspace, but all I'm really looking to do is extract the x/y coordinates so that they can be converted to a point and then from there a feature class to be used as an input

Comment: I assume your x/y coordinates are saved to a .csv. I'll edit my answer to include how to upload a .csv, display x/y and save the output as a layer file for you to then use the buffer command on.

Comment: I will try this out, thank you! I also don't know if this affects anything, but currently inPts is just a point that is dropped on the map using the FeatureSet parameter. I hope that something like this can still allow the coordinates to be transferred into a csv and then for this to properly function.